# if looping over a dataframe and creating new columns inside that loop, will it be endless?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I want to loop over a dataframe and manipulate each column. Say I do so by:

```
for feature in df:
        df[feature] = df[feature].apply(lambda x: manipulate(x))
        print (str(feature) + ' ready!')
```

Will this make me end up in an endless loop because python will iterate over all columns, including those that are newly created, or only the ones from my initial input-df?

Comment: why don't you try it ?

Comment: I did, and it is still going since a couple days. However I cannot rule out it is still running the code rather than being in an endless loop

Answer (score 0):

No, this will only loop over the initial columns in the dataframes. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x': [1,2,3,4,5], 'y': ['a','b','c','d','e']})

for col in df:
  df[col + '1'] =df[col]
```

returns:

```
    x   y   x1  y1
0   1   a   1   a
1   2   b   2   b
2   3   c   3   c
3   4   d   4   d
4   5   e   5   e
```